# ARCore Cloud Anchors without Google Cloud ( use 3rd party instead for persistent objects)?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, parse-server, arcore

**Goal:**

My main goal is to have a virtual object placed at some point and even after days when coming back see that object at the exact same location.

So the question is:

How to serialize an object of type AnchoreNode so I can send it into a file?

Comment: Im also trying to make a Anchor Server, the solution i have found is to make my own server which comunicate with anchor, following this issue https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/400 its actually not possible to create a anchor server, sadly, we are gonna have to make a reverse engine solution and emulate a anchor server.

Comment: have you looked in to Azure Spatial Anchors? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/spatial-anchors/